# How to change the flash color?

Tags: watir

I want to change the flash color when using `element.flash` method. By default its yellow.
I was able to increase the number of flash times and delay time in elements.rb file. But i dont know how to change the highlight color. 
Any idea on this?

Using different colors to highlight will be helpful if browser elements have yellow background.

Comment: Are you using watir-classic or watir-webdriver? I remember seeing the place in code where the background color is defined, it should be as easy as monkey patching the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

The flashing is based on the element's container's activeObjectHighLightColor. This is set by doing:

```
element.container.activeObjectHighLightColor = "colour"
```

Where `colour` is a valid web-friendly color (as per the [container.rb file](https://github.com/watir/watir-classic/blob/master/lib/watir-classic/container.rb)).

**Example - Flash For Individual Element**

As an example, here is changing the flash colour for the text field on the Google search:

```
#Use google search text field as a test page
ie = Watir::Browser.new
ie.goto 'www.google.ca'
e = ie.text_field(:name => 'q')

#Set the flash colour
e.container.activeObjectHighLightColor = "green"

#Flash the object, which should now be green
e.flash
```

Note:

- This will only work with Watir-classic. Watir-webdriver does the flashing differently.
- I only tested this in the latest version of watir-classic, but the code for 2.0.4 appears to be the same.

**Example - Default Flash Colour**

To change the default flash colour for everything, you need to set the `activeObjectHighLightColor` for the browser.

If you want to change it for the current browser, do:

```
ie = Watir::Browser.new
ie.activeObjectHighLightColor = "green"

ie.goto 'www.google.ca'
e = ie.text_field(:name => 'q')
e.flash
#=> Will flash green
```

If you want to change it permanently (ie so you do not have to set it each time), you can change the colour in the ie-class.rb file:

```
HIGHLIGHT_COLOR = 'yellow'
```

Comment: Thanks Justin. This works fine in Watir 2.0.4. But By default the color is yellow. So i would like to know in which file it is mentioned.

Comment: The default colour is specified in the ie-class.rb file. Though I would suggest setting the activeObjectHighLightColor  for the browser object instead (see answer update).